# Google OAuth Application Rate Limit Monitoring

Tags: google-oauth, google-authentication

[image: Google OAuth Rate Limit]

Google caps our per day token grant rate limit at 10,000 grants per day and displays our current usage rate in the Consent Screen section of our Google App in the Google API Console (see screenshot above).  Is there anyway to get this information via an API or any other way outside this simple graph representation in the Google API console?  We'd like to collect these metrics and add some threshold monitoring to alert us when we're getting close to this limit.  I haven't been able to find anyway to do this via their OAuth documentation so far.

Answer (score -1):

There is no api to get current usage of your applicaiton.

Answer (score -1):

Since a grant involves calling one of your own endpoints, can't you simply keep your own count?